# How do I get indexed vertex positions AND indexed vertex normals from wavefront .obj file into an OpenGL vertex shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, .obj

I was trying to use two Vertex Buffer Objects (VBO) and two Index Buffer Objects (IBO) in a Vertex Array Object (VAO) for rendering data from a wavefront .Obj file containing a 3D model.
The .obj file was using the [vertex/normal face definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Vertex.2Fnormal):

```
f v1//vn1 v2//vn2 v3//vn3
```

I realized that I couldn't use two IBOs for indexing with OpenGL's VAO since only one buffer object (at a time) can be bound to the GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER binding target. This means that I can't just define vertex position indices AND vertex normal indices which is a problem when I need both as input to a GLSL vertex shader.

I thought about using a "Vertex" struct encapsulating vertex position and vertex normals, but I don't know how to feed OpenGL the data as anything but one long array and when I have all my vertex position data in different objects. I guess I could use some loops to copy the data to a new array containing all the position data.

When loading the .obj file I guess I could process the data so that the normals are matched with the corresponding vertex position values.

How should I go about solving this problem?

I'm using C++ and Visual Studio 2012 with OpenGL 3.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing you must understand is, that a "vertex" is not synnonymous with "position". A vertex is the whole set of attributes; position, normal, texture coordinate, etc. OpenGL processes geometry one primitive at a time, where a primitive consists of 1 (point), 2 (line) or 3 vertices (triangle). You can not process position and normal separately, they always must go together.

Before you can process it in OpenGL you must expand the data in the .obj file. For each unique tuple of attributes introduce a new vertex with a new index and replace indexed attributes from the .obj with the indexed vertex OpenGL requires.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, datenwolf. I now understand it conceptually.

Comment: I believe I'm still missing something.
"For each unique tuple of attributes introduce a new vertex with a new index and replace indexed attributes..."
Within a face, a vertex in an obj has an associated normal. Within another face that shares the same vertex, that vertex has a different normal. Does the vertex normal attribute in OpenGL represent one normal per vertex per face, or a single normal for a single vertex regardless of which face it belongs to? Sorry for the necropost.

Comment: @JohnP: Please read the very first sentence of my answer again. If there are two vertices with the same position, but different normal, then they are *different* vertices! Wavefront OBJ files are a misnormer because they call *positions* "vertices" (they are not, they are just positions) and the face records index into "vertex" and "vertex normal" records (the proper names for the records would be "position record" and "normal record").

Comment: @datenwolf this is a clear and very helpful answer. Can you recommend any resource that goes into more detail on these issues?

Comment: @algal: nothing I'd know right at hand. Most of "us" old-fart graphics programmers – who started doing this stuff, when it was still in its technological infancy – learnt this stuff by reading other people's code and by carefully thinking about it. Some then went ahead and wrote books about it. All these things come naturally if you follow the logical progression from elementary linear algebra and basic computer architecture design.

Comment: @datenwolf yes! I aspire to the wisdom of the old farts. So I'm looking for materials that at least support that logical progression. The Graphics Codex (App Store) and 3D Computer Graphics (Gortler) are my Virgils so far.